# Useless function in Google Analytics?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, polyfills

I was looking through Google Analytics, and I came across this function (pretty-printed for readability):

```
ha = function(a) {
  var b = [];
  if (Array.prototype.indexOf) return a = b.indexOf(a), "number" ==
    typeof a ? a : -1;
  for (var c = 0; c < b.length; c++)
    if (b[c] === a) return c;
  return -1
},
```

This looks like an `Array.prototype.indexOf` polyfill. Trouble is, instead of the `var b = this;` you'd expect, there is instead `var b = [];`. I can't find any circumstance in which this would *not* return `-1`.

The last time I found something like this in Google Analytics, I had just made a mistake and it was actually functional. But... I *really* can't see where I'm going wrong with this one.

Does this code do anything? Or does it just unconditionally return `-1`?

---

Sandbox for testing:

```js
var ha = function(a) {
  var b = [];
  if (Array.prototype.indexOf) return a = b.indexOf(a), "number" ==
    typeof a ? a : -1;
  for (var c = 0; c < b.length; c++)
    if (b[c] === a) return c;
  return -1
};
```

```html
<input id="input" value="ha(5);" /><button onclick="var v=document.getElementById('input').value;console.log(v,eval(v));">Run</button>
```

Comment: where do you find that? analytics.js?

Comment: @Tushar I used the copy [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20181006023445if_/https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js), but it's not for the faint-hearted. I'm asking this question because I'm trying to figure out how it works, and I've come across something that makes no sense to me.

Comment: this can work as a secure solution in the env where Array.prototype.indexOf is overridden by somebody else. Or IE 8

Comment: @ДмитроБулах Yeah... but why `var b = [];`?

Comment: @HugoDelsing It is called. That's the most bemusing thing; it's called in an `if` statement.